# How can I remove the redundant part of reference?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

The problem I met before is there always be a redundant part appear when I cite a paper, here is my `template.tex` code,

```
\documentclass[smallextened]{svjour3}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\cite{Xia2015Who}              % cite Xia's paper

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}    % basic style, author-year citations
\bibliography{ref}             % name your BibTeX data base
\end{document}
```

Here is the code in my `ref.bib` file,

```
@inproceedings{Xia2015Who,
  title={Who should review this change?},
  author={Xia, Xin and Lo, David and Wang, Xinyu and Yang, Xiaohu},
  booktitle={IEEE International Conference on Software Maintenance and Evolution},
  pages={261-270},
  year={2015},
}
```

Finally, my citation in paper is like this, which I can't understand why. Who can help me remove the redundant part (i.e., the first part of **'Li et al(2016)Li, Li, Kim, Bissyand'e, Lo, and Traon'** in the first line of the following reference).

```
  [Xia et al(2015)Xia, Lo, Wang, and Yang] Xia X, Lo D, Wang X, Yang X (2015) Who should 
  review this change?: Putting text and ﬁle location analyses together for more accurate
  recommendations. In: IEEE International Conference on Software Maintenance and Evolut-
  ion, pp 261–270
```

Comment: I still don't know why my reference will have this redundant prefix: `Li et al(2016)Li, Li, Kim, Bissyand´e, Lo, and Traon.`

Comment: Sorry man, `Li et al(2016)Li, Li, Kim, ...` is just another similar wrong output of my reference, but I paste it by mistake. =_=! . I mean all output references all have the redundant prefix like this. I will edit the question soon.

Comment: The `cite` citation management package is designed to generate numeric-style citation call-outs. However, you're using the `spbasic` bibliography style, which is supposed to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs. Solution: Don't load the `cite` package; instead, load the `natbib` package.

Comment: @Mico , It's easy to replace the `cite` package with `natbib` package, but the paper latex template[International Journal of Automated Software Engineering](http://www.springer.com/computer/ai/journal/10515?detailsPage=pltci_2530505) give me the `cite` package. I am just confuse with it.

Comment: The `cite` package simply doesn't interact well with the `spbasic` bibliography style. If, for some reason, you must keep using the `cite` package, you will have to select a different bibliography style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the uninitiated the template file provided is not so helpful.  The bibliography style `spbasic.bst` is designed to work with the `natbib` package, but the template fails to include this. So you either need
`\usepackage{natbib}` or (as Troy points out) you can take advantage of the fact that `svjour3` class has a special option `natbib` for this:

```
\documentclass[smallextended,natbib]{svjour3}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\cite{Xia2015Who}              % cite Xia's paper

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}    % basic style, author-year citations
\bibliography{ref}             % name your BibTeX data base

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Note that you can not use the `cite` package with `natbib`, but `natbib` has package options that will emulate features provided by `cite`.  See the [`natbib` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib?lang=en).  Note also the `smallextended` option was misspelt in your code.

Comment: As a supplement to your answer, `natbib` is available as an option to be passed in the documentclass.

Comment: @Troy Good point.  Answer updated.

Comment: @Troy, as a beginner in StackExchange TeX, I am so scared to find somebody stare at me everywhere and then drive me out of this conmunity T^T .

Comment: @AndrewSwann, very nice answer for my question, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Yongfeng Thank you.  Don't be scared - every one is just trying to help.